# Header middle crossing two half columns - bootstrap

Tags: css, web, layout, responsive

I have this layout:

```
<h1>INFO</h1>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12 bg-blue">
            <div class="bi-left">
                <img src="">
                <ul>
                    <li>text</li>
                    <li>text</li>
                    <li>text</li>
                    <li>text</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12">
            <div class="bi-right">
                <img src="">
                <ul>
                    <li>text</li>
                    <li>text</li>
                    <li>text</li>
                    <li>text</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need my first half column to have blue bg even when columns get repositioned to col-12. 
And I need my h1 to be right in the middle crossing through half with blue bg to second half with basic white bg.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set it using `absolute` position.

```css
.bg-blue {
  background: blue;
}

.title {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top:  10px;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  z-index: 1;
  margin: 0;
}

.bi-left, .bi-right {
  padding: 50px 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="container-fluid">
    <h1 class="title">INFO</h1>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-xs-6 bg-blue">
            <div class="bi-left">
                <img src="">
                <ul>
                    <li>text</li>
                    <li>text</li>
                    <li>text</li>
                    <li>text</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-xs-6">
            <div class="bi-right">
                <img src="">
                <ul>
                    <li>text</li>
                    <li>text</li>
                    <li>text</li>
                    <li>text</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```